# Reduce white space below \headsepline and above \footsepline

Tags: header-footer, two-column, books, scrpage2

I want my body text to be closer to both `\headsepline` and `\footsepline`. Can this be done with `scrpage2`? Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.2pt}
\setfootsepline{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you want to reduce the space between the text and the horizontal lines at the top and the bottom of the page, so that you have something like this:

[image]

If this is what you are trying to do then you just need to specify the value of `footskip` and `headsep` when you load the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. For the page above I used:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm,left=25mm,right=25mm,
          top=30mm,bottom=30mm,footskip=5mm,headsep=0mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Well that's easy, thanks. Didn't know `geometry` could also control header and footer dimensions. Too bad there isn't an option for `footstep` and `footheight`.